# Anyone running QCA9880 / ath10k with hostapd, 802.11ac enabled?

Tags: atheros, hostapd

I have problems to get it working... I was using an atheros 11n card with ath9k driver and everything works fine (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit). Maybe I didn't compile hostapd or didn't setup the conf file correctly with the new card. So could you share your .config file to compile hostapd (since 11ac isn't enabled by Ubuntu package) and the conf file to run hostapd please? Thanks!

BTW I think the system has recognized the card already.

```
lspci -v:
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA988x 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Expansion ROM at f7a00000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

lsmod | grep ath
dm_multipath           22843  0 
scsi_dh                14882  1 dm_multipath
ath10k_pci             41335  0 
ath10k_core           133514  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    29006  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              652702  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              494330  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core

ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:03:07:12:34:56  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:109 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:27490 (27.4 KB)
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't even get the card working-- just plain hardware incompatible with my Q2900M (used two different mPCIe to regular PCIe adapters, doesn't even boot). So kudos to you on that.

I think I was using a few cards based on the reference board. The Compex WLE900VX & the SparkLan WPEA-352ACN look so similar down to the copper traces and placement of surface mount components. Both QCA9880 based... they likely do have master mode available-- I don't know as my board wouldn't boot and the other machines I tried them in booted-- but I did not see them when running lspci.

I also have a weird form factor Broadcom board from an apple airport. I ordered it from ebay: New Apple BCM94360CD 802.11ac Wifi Bluetooth 4.0 Card + Mini PCI-E Adapter ( ebay.com/itm/171521530246?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT )

I received a different adapter which worked ( ebay.com/itm/321812633609 )

But once it was working it was revealed that the driver I was using did not support AP Mode with hostapd.

Moved on to a TP-Link T8E, which works-- but again doesn't seem to have Master Mode available to enable AP mode with hostapd-- yet. Talked with TP-Link and they 'don't support' Linux/UNIX but, as long as the hardware works I don't care what they support.

I have a couple more mPCIe to PCIe adapters on order as well as some 802.11ac 2x2 cards.

-Adapters I have not tried:

Asus PCE-AC66

Asus PCE-AC68

TP-Link TP-T9E

Silex SX-PCEAC

-Adapters I attempted to get but for whatever reason couldn't:

Unex DAXB-81

The google search that served me best was "802.11ac 3x3 pcie"

www.google.com/search?q=802.11ac+3x3

Good luck to us...

The following is output I hope to see from other people.
There is an 802.11a/b/g/n card with the hardware properties I am hoping for on the 802.11ac card(s) and the 802.11ac 3x3 MIMO TP-Link Archer T8E for comparison.

```
brad@Q2900M:~$ sudo iw list

Wiphy phy1
        max # scan SSIDs: 1
        max scan IEs length: 0 bytes
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Supported Ciphers:
                * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
                * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
        Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
        Band 1:
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 1.0 Mbps
                        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
                Frequencies:
                        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        Band 2:
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
                Frequencies:
                        * 5160 MHz [32] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5170 MHz [34] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5180 MHz [36] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5190 MHz [38] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5200 MHz [40] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5210 MHz [42] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5220 MHz [44] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5230 MHz [46] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5240 MHz [48] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5250 MHz [50] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5260 MHz [52] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5270 MHz [54] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5280 MHz [56] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5290 MHz [58] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5300 MHz [60] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5310 MHz [62] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5320 MHz [64] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5330 MHz [66] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5340 MHz [68] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5350 MHz [70] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5360 MHz [72] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5370 MHz [74] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5380 MHz [76] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5390 MHz [78] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5400 MHz [80] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5410 MHz [82] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5420 MHz [84] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5430 MHz [86] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5440 MHz [88] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5450 MHz [90] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5460 MHz [92] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5470 MHz [94] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5480 MHz [96] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5490 MHz [98] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5500 MHz [100] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5510 MHz [102] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5520 MHz [104] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5530 MHz [106] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5540 MHz [108] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5550 MHz [110] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5560 MHz [112] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5570 MHz [114] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5580 MHz [116] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5590 MHz [118] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5600 MHz [120] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5610 MHz [122] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5620 MHz [124] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5630 MHz [126] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5640 MHz [128] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5650 MHz [130] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5660 MHz [132] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5670 MHz [134] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5680 MHz [136] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5690 MHz [138] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5700 MHz [140] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5710 MHz [142] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5720 MHz [144] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5725 MHz [145] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5730 MHz [146] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5735 MHz [147] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5740 MHz [148] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5745 MHz [149] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5750 MHz [150] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5755 MHz [151] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5760 MHz [152] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5765 MHz [153] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5770 MHz [154] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5775 MHz [155] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5780 MHz [156] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5785 MHz [157] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5790 MHz [158] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5795 MHz [159] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5800 MHz [160] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5805 MHz [161] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5810 MHz [162] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5815 MHz [163] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5820 MHz [164] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5825 MHz [165] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5830 MHz [166] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5840 MHz [168] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5850 MHz [170] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5860 MHz [172] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5870 MHz [174] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5880 MHz [176] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5890 MHz [178] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5900 MHz [180] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5910 MHz [182] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5920 MHz [184] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5930 MHz [186] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5940 MHz [188] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5950 MHz [190] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5960 MHz [192] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5970 MHz [194] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5980 MHz [196] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 5990 MHz [198] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6000 MHz [200] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6010 MHz [202] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6020 MHz [204] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6030 MHz [206] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6040 MHz [208] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6050 MHz [210] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6060 MHz [212] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6070 MHz [214] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6080 MHz [216] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6090 MHz [218] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6100 MHz [220] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6110 MHz [222] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6120 MHz [224] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6130 MHz [226] (30.0 dBm)
                        * 6140 MHz [228] (30.0 dBm)
        Supported commands:
                 * set_interface
                 * new_key
                 * join_ibss
                 * set_pmksa
                 * del_pmksa
                 * flush_pmksa
                 * connect
                 * disconnect
        WoWLAN support:
                 * wake up on disconnect
                 * wake up on magic packet
                 * can do GTK rekeying
                 * wake up on GTK rekey failure
                 * wake up on EAP identity request
        software interface modes (can always be added):
        interface combinations are not supported
        Device supports scan flush.
Wiphy phy0
        max # scan SSIDs: 4
        max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Device supports RSN-IBSS.
        Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
        Device supports T-DLS.
        Supported Ciphers:
                * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
                * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
        Available Antennas: TX 0x7 RX 0x7
        Configured Antennas: TX 0x7 RX 0x7
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * WDS
                 * monitor
                 * mesh point
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
        Band 1:
                Capabilities: 0x11ef
                        RX LDPC
                        HT20/HT40
                        SM Power Save disabled
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        TX STBC
                        RX STBC 1-stream
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-23
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 1.0 Mbps
                        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
                Frequencies:
                        * 2412 MHz [1] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2417 MHz [2] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2422 MHz [3] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2427 MHz [4] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2432 MHz [5] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2437 MHz [6] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2442 MHz [7] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2447 MHz [8] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2452 MHz [9] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2457 MHz [10] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2462 MHz [11] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2467 MHz [12] (15.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 2472 MHz [13] (15.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
        Band 2:
                Capabilities: 0x11ef
                        RX LDPC
                        HT20/HT40
                        SM Power Save disabled
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        TX STBC
                        RX STBC 1-stream
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-23
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
                Frequencies:
                        * 5180 MHz [36] (15.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5200 MHz [40] (15.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5220 MHz [44] (15.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5240 MHz [48] (15.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5260 MHz [52] (16.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                          DFS state: usable (for 200478 sec)
                        * 5280 MHz [56] (16.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                          DFS state: usable (for 200478 sec)
                        * 5300 MHz [60] (16.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                          DFS state: usable (for 200478 sec)
                        * 5320 MHz [64] (16.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                          DFS state: usable (for 200478 sec)
                        * 5500 MHz [100] (disabled)
                        * 5520 MHz [104] (disabled)
                        * 5540 MHz [108] (disabled)
                        * 5560 MHz [112] (disabled)
                        * 5580 MHz [116] (disabled)
                        * 5600 MHz [120] (disabled)
                        * 5620 MHz [124] (disabled)
                        * 5640 MHz [128] (disabled)
                        * 5660 MHz [132] (disabled)
                        * 5680 MHz [136] (disabled)
                        * 5700 MHz [140] (disabled)
                        * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        Supported commands:
                 * new_interface
                 * set_interface
                 * new_key
                 * start_ap
                 * new_station
                 * new_mpath
                 * set_mesh_config
                 * set_bss
                 * authenticate
                 * associate
                 * deauthenticate
                 * disassociate
                 * join_ibss
                 * join_mesh
                 * remain_on_channel
                 * set_tx_bitrate_mask
                 * frame
                 * frame_wait_cancel
                 * set_wiphy_netns
                 * set_channel
                 * set_wds_peer
                 * tdls_mgmt
                 * tdls_oper
                 * probe_client
                 * set_noack_map
                 * register_beacons
                 * start_p2p_device
                 * set_mcast_rate
                 * Unknown command (104)
                 * connect
                 * disconnect
        Supported TX frame types:
                 * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
        Supported RX frame types:
                 * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * managed: 0x40 0xd0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
        software interface modes (can always be added):
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 2048, #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
                   total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
                 * #{ WDS } <= 2048,
                   total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
        HT Capability overrides:
                 * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
                 * maximum A-MSDU length
                 * supported channel width
                 * short GI for 40 MHz
                 * max A-MPDU length exponent
                 * min MPDU start spacing
        Device supports TX status socket option.
        Device supports HT-IBSS.
        Device supports low priority scan.
        Device supports scan flush.
        Device supports AP scan.



brad@Q2900M:~$ lspci -nn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register [8086:0f00] (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display [8086:0f31] (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0f23] (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB xHCI [8086:0f35] (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller [1080]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine [8086:0f18] (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0f48] (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0f4a] (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0f4c] (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0f4e] (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit [8086:0f1c] (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0f12] (rev 0e)
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Integrated Device Technology, Inc. [IDT] PES12N3A PCI Express Switch [111d:8018] (rev 0e)
03:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Integrated Device Technology, Inc. [IDT] PES12N3A PCI Express Switch [111d:8018] (rev 0e)
03:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Integrated Device Technology, Inc. [IDT] PES12N3A PCI Express Switch [111d:8018] (rev 0e)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82575GB Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10d6] (rev 02)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82575GB Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10d6] (rev 02)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82575GB Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10d6] (rev 02)
05:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82575GB Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10d6] (rev 02)
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 11)
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but this is not an answer; this is a rant. Have a look around the site to what constitutes a good answer, [edit] your answer, and leave another comment to me and I might upvote instead of downvote.  @DavidFoerster: I was wrong...

Comment: @Fabby - think with a bit of editing this is a valid answer now.

Comment: @fossfreedom: I tried that too, but the OP just rolled back.  Downvote removed.  We'll see what happens...

Comment: Why on God's green earth would you remove the lspci and iw list output? If you personally are not working on 802.11ac development, hands off. There are thousands of other posts that you can make less useful, why are you here? You script kiddies get a little bit of power and all of a sudden you go messing with things that aren't any of your business. It was a rant, and put it back if you don't mind...